# Same view on navigation in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, ios6

In my application i use the following code to navigate to a new view on receiving a click, It is working properly on iOS5. However, When i try with ios6 it is showing the current view and Is not goin to the next view. Do i need to change anything for ios6 in this code.

please help me to solve.

```
scoreview *sview=[[scoreview alloc]  initWithNibName:@"scoreview" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sview animated:YES];
```

Comment: In iOS6, Have you test to see if self.naviationController == nil ?

Comment: @VinceBurn can you make clear what you asking

Comment: NSLog (@"self.navigationController == %@", self.navigationController); When there in no push what's the result of this?

Comment: just check [self.navigationController presentViewController:sview animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @VinceBurn this is is the result `self.navigationController == <UINavigationController: 0x7aa0eb0>`

Comment: @Rose this is output `Warning: Attempt to present <scoreview: 0x7e61a30> on <UINavigationController: 0x7aa0eb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: where are u calling this method??

Comment: 2 Questions : scoreview is a subclass of UIViewController? How are you putting your UINavigationController in your Window? iOS 6 is more touchy than iOS 5 about that.

Comment: @VinceBurn yes Scoreview is  subclass of UIViewController,i initialise  Uinavigationcontroller in appdelegate file itself

Comment: @Rose when score button clicks i call that method

Comment: not where, how do you add it?

Comment: @Fazil:check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748845/present-more-than-one-modalview-in-appdelegate

Comment: @VinceBurn  `navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];` in appdelgate file

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines:

```
 scoreview *sview=[[scoreview alloc]  initWithNibName:@"scoreview" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:sview animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check your view is Correctly connected with UIInterfaceBuilder